# How to convert concatenation to template in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, concatenation

I am new to programming. Recently, I started learning Kotlin.
I got a suggestion with this code:

```
var cont = "N"
var result:Int?
result = 45
println (cont + " + " + result)
```

It suggests converting this `{" + "}` to a template, but I do not know how?

Comment: You can hit Alt + Enter and make IDEA automatically do it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In Kotlin, you can use string templates to remove all the concatenation symbols in your code. They always start with a `$`.

For example in your code, you could have done this:

```kotlin
println("$cont + $result")
```

This would print the same result as your original code, just more concise and readable. This can even be done on arbitrary expressions you just have to wrap it in curly braces.

For example:

```kotlin
val cont = "ALEC"
println("Hi ${cont.toLowerCase()}") //prints Hi alec
```

As mentioned in the comments, IntelliJ will do this automagically by hitting `ALT + Enter` when the hint is suggested.

Comment: So is the sole purpose of templating by using dollar is readability ? If so why? 
By the way I am from java background and recently moved to kotlin. So even by using + symbol to concatenate did not cause any trouble.

Comment: @AkashVerma I'd assume readability and ease of use, far easier to write `$` then worry about all the `+` and `"` like Java. Additionally, you are correct. Kotlin allows for both ways.

Comment: "far easier to write $ then worry about all the + and " like Java" -- Make sense. Thanks.